# How to find my ipv4 ip address

Tags: release-juno, networking, internet

where can I find my Ipv4 ip address, I tired all sorts of different commands I need help.(I am new)

Answer (score 0):

For Public IP address run this `curl bot.whatismyipaddress.com`

For Private IP address run this `ifconfig -a`